# How to remote access my mysql database?

Tags: mysql

can you please help people, i made an application which will be used by few friends of mine, but the application is written with connection method: Standard (TCP/IP), i was thinking it will be easy, just give them the server IP and port and done, but I'am stuck in this problem where i cant access my database via public IP? I successfully port forwarded 3306 but still i can't connect to my mysql server via public ip, only by localhost or lan ip. Why is this so hard? i dont need any security kind of things, just ip,port,username and password. whats upp.... :/// i asked on 30 forums nobody is helping... server is running on windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely insecure, but if you insist, change the "bind-address" line in my.cnf from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the bind-address in my.cnf to 0.0.0.0
2. Restart database server
3. Run this query:

   UPDATE mysql.user SET host = '%' WHERE user= 'YOUR_MYSQL_USERNAME';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Edit: This should go in comment, but i don't have enough rep. Are you sure your ports are correctly forwarded? Also make sure, that your ISP doesn't block it.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL listens to the local machine by default. We can change that by **bind-address setting** in **my.cnf** on the server. Change this setting to listen on the public IP address by changing **bind-address to 0.0.0.0**. Also check for the **skip-networking isn't switched on**.

Comment: still wont connect :/ also in the my.ini, there wasnt any bind address so i write it mysql. here is a pic, http://oi61.tinypic.com/16bhqp3.jpg
the bind address line, i writed.